# XmlReader.Create() The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden / Ok in Browser

Tags: c#, rss, xmlreader

Need a bit of guidance. I'm trying to read a public RSS feed from
    http://data.eso.sa.gov.au/prod/cfs/crimson/cfs_current_incidents.xml

I can read it via any browser without problem but doing so via code produces the "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" error.

I've inserted various user agents to try and get around the problem but have failed completely.
I don't understand why it works in a browser but not in my code. I use the same code for other feeds, surely any permissions issues would apply to the browser as well as my code?

Here's the relevant// code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
// webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Chrome/15.0.874.121");
// webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
// webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/57.0.4");
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136");

using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(webClient.OpenRead("http://data.eso.sa.gov.au/prod/cfs/crimson/cfs_current_incidents.xml")))
   {  //etc etc
   }
```

Its failing at XmlReader.Create

Comment: Well I get a 403 when attempting to view via browser so...

Comment: I've tried every browser, and get 403.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>412518E77D3F091F</RequestId>
  <HostId>HefwTRX6OsIXgMkG76aLUMduhFA9z/SZ/Xs//r6Vz3V6sWJg+oyoKwM2TyMsou2ssNLzePBWDkY=</HostId>
</Error>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have embarrassingly figured this one out.
It appears that during all my mucking about, the address changed and 'crimson' should be 'criimson' - an extra i in it and it works.
That naturally upset the server hence the response. 
Not sure how I achieved that as it was a cut and paste from the browser, ho hum...

Your responses helped me track this down so thanks for that.